# Use Less to expand variable to string

Tags: string, colors, less

Is there a way in **Less** to expand the contents of a variable to a string?

My specific use case:

```less
@thecolor: #3B98D5

.theclass {
  ...
}

.theclass:before {
  content: "#3B98D5"; // How do I use @thecolor here instead?
}
```

Then in HTML:

```html
<div class="theclass">
   #3B98D5             <!-- What I want in the end -->
</div>
```

The use case is to create a static page that shows a set of colors, where I would like the color code in the HTML, but only ever specify it in the Less.

So in the end I want it to be a HTML text node. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Please give a reason why you down vote the question. This was not apparent to me from reading the less documentation. I had tried using content `"@theclass"` but did not know about `"@{theclass}"`

Comment: I can't explain why some have downvoted (as I haven't) but it is more likely because variable interpolations are considered to be some of the basic stuff. I am not saying you should've known this earlier but that's probably the reason. In fact, I expected a duplicate post to appear in the "Related" section but no exact dupes appeared.

Comment: Ok. But yea, this is a question and answer site, I tried to find this specific question. I'd just prefer people told me their reason to downvote. Anyway, I now realise that the less documentation has a language reference as well as a built-in function reference. I only looked in the language reference, looking in the other part made this a lot more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enclose the variable within double quotes and use [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation) (Format: `@{var-name}`).

```
@thecolor: #3B98D5;

.theclass:before {
  content: "@{thecolor}";
}
```

The variable needs to be enclosed within quotes because otherwise the content property will not take it as a string and display. When you use `"@theccolor"`, Less compiler just treats it as a normal string (and not as a variable which is present within quotes needing to be evaluated). The `"@{theclass}"` is the format for using variable interpolation which lets the compiler know that the value inside quotes is a variable which needs to be evaluated.

```css
.theclass:before {
  content: "#3B98D5";
}

.theclasswrong:before {
  content: #3B98D5;
}
```

```html
<div class='theclass'>- Correct Output</div>
<div class='theclasswrong'> - Will not give output without quotes</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok, I had tried with quotes, but I did not know about the difference between `"@theclass"` and `"@{theclass}"`. Maybe you could describe that difference in the answer as well? Thanks

Comment: @Joakim: When you use `"@theclass"`, Less compiler just treats it as a string (and not a variable which is present within quotes needing to be evaluated). The `"@{theclass}"` is the format for using variable interpolation which lets the compiler know that the value inside quotes is a variable which needs to be evaluated.